# Convert byte array to TimeSpan or DateTime

Tags: c#

I have a problem converting Byte array `Byte1 = { 10, 10 ,59 }` which translate into `10:10:59 (AM)`.
I tried different encoding methods to convert the string to use with `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` but with no success.
All I need is to convert to string with `"313031303539"`.

Comment: what's the error and how did you tried?

Comment: Where does the string "313031303539" come into this? Your question is very unclear. It would really help if you would show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: He seems to want to convert the 101059 characters to the ascii character codes for those digits: 313031303539.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var time = new TimeSpan(myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks Jmcilhinney for the quick response and a correct answer.